# Scala XML performance vs. Java XML

Tags: java, xml, performance, scala

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the direction, or inform me of some benchmarks, which is comparing how Scala's XML library does compared to the typical solution in Java.

I'm thinking on measurements of parsing and selecting XML elements.

Thanks in advance.

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[These benchmarks](http://anti-xml.org/performance.html) from the ["Anti-XML" team](http://anti-xml.org/) are a good place to start, and [other parts of the site](http://anti-xml.org/faq.html) highlight some of the problems with the current `scala.xml` approach.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I forgot to mention I have been looking on the anti-xml site. Do you now other places, with a more comprehensive test? Thanks.

Comment: You could look into the [code that was used for those benchmarks](https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml/tree/master/src/test/scala/com/codecommit/antixml/performance). I'm not aware off the top of my head of other `scala.xml` vs. `javax.xml` evaluations.

Comment: Anti-XML team link is rotten now. :( Please avoid link only answers.

Answer (score 2):

Scales Xml has performance roughly 20-30% slower than Xerces/JAXP deferred (the default setting but overall worse JAXP option for large xml) [details and charts](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.1/0.2.1/MemoryOptimisation.html).

Interestingly Scales is 20-30% faster than JAXP for full parsing while having the low memory usage of JAXP deferred.  In both cases you get a fully immutable document.  Scales is also typically 30-40% faster than Scala parsing.